# ZSH syntax formatting and coloring for shell scripting

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

There are 2 features (not sure what they are called) in fish shell that will automatically format the syntax with color when doing shell scripting, similar to what a ipython do.

Does anyone know how I can get similar functionality (with ZSH plugins)?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting).

If you have *zgen*, you can load it with:

```
zgen load zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting
```